# python overwrite bytes from offset1 to offset2

Tags: python, file-io

I've seen multiple tutorials in python, played around a bit with python file write(), tell(), seek() functions and also os.write(), lseek() functions.

But I still don't get how can I do the following:
What I have:
In  a file I know the start_offset and end_offset bytes. And I need to replace the bytes from start_offset to end_offset with  a different set of bytes. How do I do this??

ftell() returns me the start_offset and similarly regex + ftell() returns me the end offset
I have the bytes that will overwrite the original ones in the file.

But write() only takes  a string to write. Also how do I overwrite from start_pos to end_pos??

appreciate any pointers/suggestions

Comment: There is no need to shout; can you turn off your capslock next time?

Comment: Assuming the overwrite has the same size as `end_pos - start_pos`, simply fseek and then write

Comment: Just to clarify -- the replacement bytes are exactly the same size as the first set of bytes or different? If it is a different size, you need to replace the entire file from start_offset through the end of the file.

Comment: sorry...will turn off shoutout next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite your shouted denial, you *can* use `mmap` here.

If you look at the [`mmap` constructor in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap), it takes parameters for `offset` and `length`. On most platforms, both have to be a multiple of the `PAGESIZE` or similar value, but that's not too hard.

So:

```
try:
    PAGESIZE = mmap.PAGESIZE
except NameError:
    PAGESIZE = mmap.ALLOCATION_GRANULARITY

def overwrite(fileobj, start, end, newbytes):
    startoffset, startremainder = divmod(start, PAGESIZE)
    offset = startoffset * PAGESIZE
    endoffset, endremainder = divmod(end, PAGESIZE)
    length = (endoffset + 1) * PAGESIZE - offset
    map = mmap.mmap(fileobj.fileno(), offset=offset, length=length,
                    access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
    map[startremainder:startremainder+end-start] = newbytes
```

This has the nice advantage that if `len(newbytes) != end - start` you'll get a nice exception from `mmap`, instead of overwriting more or less of the file than you intended and leaving things corrupted.

But it's probably simpler to use `seek`, as in Martijn Pieters's answer. Here's the same function with `seek`:

```
def overwrite(fileobj, start, end, newbytes):
    if len(newbytes) != end - start:
        raise ValueError('overwrite cannot expand or contract a file')
    fileobj.seek(start)
    fileobj.write(newbytes)
```

Still, it's worth knowing what `mmap` can do so you don't dismiss it in useful cases in the future.

(Also, with some versions of Python, on some platforms, you can have files that are too big to `seek` in. For example, a linux `/proc/*/map` is a sparse file with a size of `1<<64`, but on some distros, Python can't find `fseeko` and therefore can't seek any farther than `1<<63`. So, knowing the alternative ways to do this—`os.lseek`, `mmap`, etc.—may help you work around a problem one day.)

Answer (score 3):

You write the exact number of characters == bytes, after `.seek()`-ing back to your `start_offset` position. These then overwrite the data that was there before.

You can split that up into multiple writes, even writes of one character (byte) at a time if needed.